# jQuery $.inArray: execute till return -1

Tags: jquery

I ran into a problem with `$.inArray`. I want to check if my date is a holiday or xyz holiday date as per business requirement; if true then substract a day by one day. Now the problem is, again with the new date I want to check if the new date is also a holiday until the new date is not holiday i.e. $.inArray will return -1. but the code given below will go into infinite loop

```
var callingDatesFlag = true;
newCallDate = "1";
callingDates = ["1","4","5"]

    while(callingDatesFlag){
      if(jQuery.inArray( newCallDate , callingDates)){
        console.log("found");
        // date = date - 1 // pseudo to understand
        // check again date is holiday or not
      }
      else{
          callingDatesFlag = false;
        console.log("not found");
      }
    }
```

Comment: So check for `jQuery.inArray( newCallDate , callingDates) > -1` because `-1` is truthly value in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var callingDatesFlag = true;
    newCallDate = "1";
    callingDates = ["1","4","5"];
    if($.inArray( newCallDate , callingDates) > -1) {
        callingDatesFlag = true;
    }
    console.log(callingDatesFlag);
```